# How can I add a watermark to a PDF using pypdf?

Tags: pypdf

I'm currently implementing codes using pypdf to change texts in pdf like this.
I was wondering if there are ways to add new transparent watermark or texts in the existing pdf content.

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

reader = PdfReader(pdf_path)
writer = PdfWriter()
for page in reader.pages:
    texts = page.extract_text()
    new_text = texts.replace("text", "test")

# TODO : add watermark and change texts

with open("new.pdf", "wb") as output:
    writer.write(output)
```

Comment: You should typically avoid asking two question within one. I clarified your question to the one that is actually possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of `pypdf` and `PyPDF2`. Please use `pypdf` in future.

`pypdf` does **not** provide a way to change texts in a PDF.

However, you can add a **watermark**: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/add-watermark.html#watermark-underlay

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union, Literal, List

from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader


def watermark(
    content_pdf: Path,
    stamp_pdf: Path,
    pdf_result: Path,
    page_indices: Union[Literal["ALL"], List[int]] = "ALL",
):
    reader = PdfReader(content_pdf)
    if page_indices == "ALL":
        page_indices = list(range(0, len(reader.pages)))

    writer = PdfWriter()
    for index in page_indices:
        content_page = reader.pages[index]
        mediabox = content_page.mediabox

        # You need to load it again, as the last time it was overwritten
        reader_stamp = PdfReader(stamp_pdf)
        image_page = reader_stamp.pages[0]

        image_page.merge_page(content_page)
        image_page.mediabox = mediabox
        writer.add_page(image_page)

    with open(pdf_result, "wb") as fp:
        writer.write(fp)
```